# What do we call numbers that are neither prime nor composite?

Tags: prime-numbers, terminology

I'm writing an Excel program that reads "PRIME" in A2 if the number in A1 is prime, and "COMPOSITE" if the number in A1 is composite. (The formula in A2 is `=IF(((COS(PI()*(FACT(A1-1)+1)/A1))^2=1)*AND(A1<>1),"Prime","Composite")` in case you wanted to know.) Only problem is, this formula basically looks at the number in A1 and thinks: "Is this number prime? If it is, then I'll say "Prime". If it's NOT prime, I'll say "composite".". The issue with this is what happens when we put "1" in A1. The computer thinks: "Is this number here prime? Hmm... just checked and no, it's not. Guess that means it's composite!" when we know that 1 is actually *not* composite. Is there a term for numbers that are neither prime nor composite so I have a reasonable output for A1=1? If so, how would I implement this?

Comment: To the person who downvoted– do you think you could explain how I could improve this question so I can improve it? This would help out a lot, and thank you in advance :D

Comment: I'd say 1 is a unit, since it is invertible

Comment: Yes, $1$ and $-1$ are the units of the ring $\Bbb Z$. The question how to "implement" this, is not about mathematics. I would implement it simply as $n=1$ (or $n=-1$).

Comment: @DietrichBurde So the units of the ring ℂ would be {x∈ ℂ:|x|=1}?

Comment: No, $\mathbb C$, is a field, so everything is a unit (except 0).

Comment: First have a look at the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory)) of a unit in a ring, before thinking about examples.

Comment: Can someone briefly explain or give a reference for the test of being prime using $cos$ and factorials?

Comment: @AlgTop1854 The function ((x-1)!+1)/x is a function that returns an integer if x is prime or 1 and a non-integer if x is composite. Now consider the function cos(πx). It hits is maximum of 1 on all even integers and hits its minimum of -1 on all odd integers. SO when x is an integer, cos(πx) is either 1 or -1. So if we combine these two and do cos(π*((x-1)!+1)/x) then we have a formula that gives ±1 if x is prime or 1 and another number between -1 and 1 otherwise. Squaring this turns all the negative values positive making it such that cos(π*((x-1)!+1)/x) gives 1 if x is prime or 1.

Comment: @AlgTop1854 Hope this helps– in case you didn't get it there's a video on it here (with the timestamp linked): https://youtu.be/j5s0h42GfvM?si=BvxEbKTRxGdwLPLB&t=240

Comment: What output does your program give for zero? What about for negative numbers?

Comment: @The_Animator very much so - thanks!